# Why does git log --diff-filter=A not show the earliest version of file in the repository?

Tags: git

I was interested in seeing the first version of SCHED_REALTME algortihm as a part of the source tree (it was introduced to Linux in version 3.14) [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCHED_DEADLINE). I checked out the repository and from **master**, did the following:

```
git log --diff-filter=A -- [path to the deadline.c file]
```

and it showed me this commit:

```
commit aab03e05e8f7e26f51dee792beddcb5cca9215a5                                                                                   
Author: Dario Faggioli <raistlin@linux.it>                                                                                        
Date:   Thu Nov 28 11:14:43 2013 +0100
```

But on the Wikipedia page (link above), they are saying that the algorithm was first merged into Linux tree in this commit a0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8, and I was indeed able to check out into this commit and see the file.

The question. Isn't the option I passed to `git log` supposed to show me the commit from Wikipedia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia page says:

> The **last** version was merged into the mainline Linux kernel (commit
>   number a0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8[30]), and is since
>   then a regular part of it.

so they don't say that this was the first introduction of that code. This corresponds with the analysis of both commits:

```
commit aab03e05e8f7e26f51dee792beddcb5cca9215a5
Author: Dario Faggioli <raistlin@linux.it>
Date:   Thu Nov 28 11:14:43 2013 +0100

commit a0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8
Merge: 9326657abe1a eaad45132c56
Author: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
Date:   Mon Jan 20 10:42:08 2014 -
```

so `aab03e05e8f7e26f51dee792beddcb5cca9215a5` is clearly older than `a0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8`. Also

```
git merge-base aab03e05e8f7e26f51dee792beddcb5cca9215a5 a0fa1dd3cdbccec9597fe53b6177a9aa6e20f2f8
```

tells me what is their common ancestor, and the answer is:

```
aab03e05e8f7e26f51dee792beddcb5cca9215a5
```

so that seems to be the real ancestor commit that introduced the `deadline.c` file.

#### conclusion

`git log --diff-filter=A` does what you expect it to do :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify `--all` branches and possibly `--follow` to detect file renames

```
git log --all --follow --diff-filter=A -- [path to the deadline.c file]
```